# Create JIRA Ticket with JIRA Version 3.12

Tags: java, c#, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to Automate JIRA ticket create process,for which i have got below links stating to use JIRA Rest API.

1.[JIRA REST API link](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue)

2.[Code project Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/825377/Creating-a-Issue-in-Jira-using-Rest-Api)

But our current JIRA version is :(Professional Edition, Version: 3.12.3-#302), which we can't upgrade it to newer versions 5.0 or later.When executing this API code by using required credentials and parameters, i am getting below error as return message.

[image]
It seems,JIRA REST API is made applicable from version 5.0 or later. If anyone has any other way achieving this,let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Before the REST APIs for JIRA were added (this started in JIRA 4), there were SOAP and XML-RPC interfaces (they were removed in JIRA 7).

You can still find links to documentation for older JIRA versions on [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/alldoc/jira-documentation-directory-71598773.html).

It seems that the online JIRA 3 documentation does not work very well anymore though, but you can try the docs for JIRA 4 instead. They seem to have working links. Ie:

- [Developer tutorials](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA040/Developer+Tutorials)
- [JIRA RPC Services](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA040/JIRA+RPC+Services)